# How to trigger an "update" event for jQuery-sortable in JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, testing, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to test sorting made with jQuery sortable from within my integration tests. In order to do so, the testing-framework (capybara, selenium) allows me to call `page.execute_script("activeAdminSortable().sortable().update()")`.

By triggering the `update` event with the proper parameters, in I can simulate a drag-and-drop to test if it works. The relevant parts of the JavaScript code is:

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('tbody .grabber').parents('tbody').activeAdminSortable();
  });

  $.fn.activeAdminSortable = function() {
    this.sortable({
      update: function(event, ui) {
        $.ajax({
          axis: 'y',
          cursor: 'move',
          url: ui.item.find('[data-sort-url]').data('sort-url'),
          type: 'post',
          data: { position: ui.item.index() + 1 },
          success: activeAdminSortableFlashFinished
        });
      }
    });

    this.disableSelection();
  }
})(jQuery);
```

I need to find a way to trigger the `update` event and pass it the correct parameters. Is there any easy way to craft such an `event`, and `ui` parameter? And to trigger the `update`.

Alternatively, I could write some JavaScript that actually grabs, drags and drops the items, but that seems rather brittle to me. Or is that trivial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `.trigger("update")` where you have `.update()`

Comment: The dot after trigger is not correct.  You want `.trigger("update");

Answer (score 1):

I am using `$('#sortable').trigger('sortupdate')` successfully for this same purpose.